# Python Pweave code width

Tags: pweave

The default value of the code width is 70, this can be a waste of space in the output. I'm wondering how I can change it to 80 and make it the default value.

I looked at the Pweave documentation, but didn't find the relevant information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change this at the moment. You can open an issue or pull request on Github if you'd like to see this added as chunk option.